# How do we determine the pressure at the surface of a star?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, astrophotography

Is there any means to do so?

I know there are some means to determine the surface temperature.

Comment: Which pressure?  There is magnetic, thermal, ram, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Stars don't have a well defined surface. If you plot the density as a function of radial distance then it falls smoothly with distance and in principle is non-zero out to very large distances. A star is basically a ball of (ionised) gas. If you take another example of a ball of gas (well, a spherical shell of gas), i.e. the Earth's atmosphere, it doesn't have a well defined outer surface and neither does the ball of gas that makes up a star.

Stars appear to have a reasonably well defined surface, but what we are seeing is the point where the plasma ceases to be opaque. This is the top of the [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere). Calculating the opacity of the plasma in a star is a complicated business. I found [some details here](http://www.astro.utu.fi/~cflynn/Stars/l7.html) and I'm sure Googling will find other descriptions of the calculation.

Given the complexity of the situation there isn't a simple equation to describe the pressure at the top of the photosphere though we can be sure the pressure is going to be significant because the density is still quite significant. For example [this data sheet from NASA](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/sunfact.html) gives the pressure at the top of the photosphere in the Sun as 0.868 millibarr.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define what you mean by the "surface". Conventionally the optical photosphere of a star is defined in term of its optical depth to radiation - usually the [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere) is said to be where the optical depth reaches 2/3.

Clearly, the gas at this optical depth has a pressure - and this is what one would normally talk about in terms of the surface pressure of the star, although in reality of course stellar atmosphere models define the run of temperature and pressure with optical depth in the star.

To determine the pressure one needs to know something about the temperature and density at the photosphere. Conveniently, these things can be estimated by analysing the spectrum of a star. The overall shape of the spectrum is temperature sensitive, as are the ratios of absorption line strengths due to various transitions between energy levels of ionised and neutral species of the same chemical element. The density/pressure can be estimated by very detailed modelling of the profile of absorption lines. Collisions with other neutral atoms or the electric fields of nearby ions can perturb energy levels leading to broadening of the spectral lines that is dependent on the density of the gas. This is often referred to as "pressure broadening".

Answer (score 0):

The gasses in a stellar surface (photosphere) are radiating, and their
spectrum includes both thermal (doppler shift, black-body brightness
dependence) and pressure (linewidth broadening) effects.   It is 
possible to determine pressure and temperature from the spectrum, 
at the photosphere and perhaps (with some difficulty)
above the photosphere in the stellar corona.